# Where to place custom css/js in Shiny App?

Tags: css, r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a Shiny app that I've been running locally which has custom css. I've placed this in the `www` dir together with the `index.html` file and this has been working smoothly. Now I've been deploying this app to a Shiny-server, and everything worked except that my custom style sheets were not loaded.

In the following guide: http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/os/latest/#host-a-directory-of-applications it states that static assets should be placed in a common directory for all Shiny apps, like this:

```
+---/srv/shiny-server
|   +---shinyApp1
|       +---server.R
|       +---ui.R
|   +---shinyApp2
|       +---server.R
|       +---ui.R
|   +---assets
|       +---style.css
|       +---script.js
```

And if I do that and link to the css like this:

```
<link href="../assets/css/full.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

It works. However I would like to know if there is any way that I can store the assets for each application within that apps folder structure, optimally getting something like this:

```
+---/srv/shiny-server
|   +---shinyApp1
|       +---server.R
|       +---www
|            |---index.html
|            |---css
|                 |---my_custom.css
```

and referencing the css in the the `index.html` like this:

```
<link href="css/full.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

However if I try to reference the css in that way it cannot be loaded. Is there any configuration that I can fix that will make this work? Or am I stuck with copying the assets of each app into the `assets` directory?

Comment: When using a a `ui.R` vs an  `index.html`-based Shiny app I specify just the base CSS file (e.g. the equiv of `href="mystyles.css"`) as a `tags$link` `href` target. I'll see if I can throw together a minimal `index.html` app to see what the difference is.

Comment: make it `href="./css/full.css"` and it should work (just tried it at http://shiny.dds.ec/test) but it also seems to work (for me) without the `./` (as you'll see from that example). If you bring up Chrome (or other browser) developer tools, is it showing that that CSS file isn't loading?

Comment: @hrbrmstr: I've tried both with and without `./` and in the console I see: `htttp://myserver:3838/sdashboard/css/full.css 404 (Not Found)`. Referencing in this way (`<link href="css/full.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`) works as long as I run it locally, but breaks with the error above when I try it on the Shiny server.

Comment: Hmm. I'm running a pretty standard Shiny config on that shiny.dds.ec box (Ubuntu base; latest RStudio & R) and just proxy the port 80 connection to 3838 (i.e. i still have the shiny server running on 3838). Have you modified any of the base server config settings?

Comment: I'm running of a Scientific Linux (6.3) machine and I don't have any proxy setup, and my config should be standard. This is what it looks like: https://gist.github.com/johandahlberg/9813703

Comment: same exact .conf on my end. hate to ask the next question (it's far too basic) but you sure it's 444 or 644 perms on the css file?

Comment: I have 644 permissions on the files. But the dir was not listable, so this was a classical beginners mistake. I'll blame it on that the hours getting late here in Sweden. Thank you so much for your time @hrbrmstr!

Comment: No trouble at all. And, that's not a beginner's mistake. Happens more than you want to believe to everyone. Rly glad I cld help!